# libGDX's plan for OpenGL deprecation

Tags: opengl, libgdx, game-engine, metal, vulkan

libGDX is based on OpenGL (ES), but iOS 12 has officially deprecated OpenGL. There will be tons of job to do if libGDX wants to evolve. For commercial engines, they have started long to adapt to the OpenGL deprecation. Any plan from libGDX team? Or have they already started the works?

Comment: That's a question which should be directed to the libgdx developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially they were reluctant to support Vulkan. Recently they are looking into both of Metal and Vulkan support by using ANGLE as backend.

> Metal/Vulkan Support [Planned]
>
> We are well aware that Apple has deprecated OpenGL (ES) on iOS and macOS. Thus, we are looking into Metal/Vulkan support in the near future. Projects like ANGLE look very promising for this.

See their [roadmap](https://libgdx.com/roadmap/).

Currently, ANGLE's Metal support is still in progress. Once it has done, the libGDX developer team will work on. I hope so.

Answer (score 1):

Already an [issue](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/5251) for the same on LibGDX issue tracker.

Discussed possibilities :

- Replace OPENGL/Adding support of metal

  All rendering code in libGDX is based on the GLES API. Adding Metal would
  require a complete rewrite of all rendering code, which would essentially
  mean an almost rewrite of libGDX.
- Software implementation of OpenGL on top of Metal (writing a wrapper)

  1. [MoltenGL](https://moltengl.com/) is an implementation of the OpenGL ES 2.0 API that runs on Apple's Metal graphics framework.
  2. [Angle](https://github.com/google/angle), Vulkan is in progress(may be in future it support metal.)